# Symfony2 update row from array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want update row setting new values from array, now Iset one by one aribute:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $company = $em->getRepository('CatalogWebBundle:ComCompany')
        ->findOneBy(
            array('cmpCode' => $id)
        );

    $company->setCmpName($_POST['name']);
    $company->setCmpCode($_POST['code']);
    $em->flush();
```

Maybe exist solution to set all atributes from array, some like this ?

```
$company = $_POST;
```

Comment: Generally you have two options, you can use symfony forms or you can add a function to your entity that populates values from an array.

Comment: Why use a framework if you're not going to utilize the tools that they offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Symfony Form and use like this:

```
<?php

$request = $this->getRequest(); // or inject Request to the action method like myAction(Request $request)

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$company = $em->getRepository('CatalogWebBundle:ComCompany')
  ->findOneBy(
      array('cmpCode' => $id)
);

$form = $this->createForm('formName', $company);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isValid()) {
  // if you want, you can get entity here,
  // but passing an entity in 2nd param of createForm
  // provides automatic binding data
  $data = $form->getData();

  $em->flush();

  // do some action after submitting form...
  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('companies'));
}
```

Read more about creating forms:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

And about regitering forms as services for futher use named form in `createForm('NAME_HERE', $bindObjectHere)`:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services